# how to stop fadeout in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fadein, fade, fadeout

```
    var menuBtn =        jQuery(".menu-btn"),
        crossBtn =       jQuery(".cross-btn"),
        toggleMenu =     jQuery(".toggle-menu");
```

// Open Menu

```
    function menuOpen () {
        toggleMenu.fadeIn(400);
        crossBtn.show();
        menuBtn.hide();
    }

    menuBtn.click(function(){
         menuOpen();
    });
```

// Close Menu

```
    function menuClose () {
        toggleMenu.fadeOut(400);
        menuBtn.show();
        crossBtn.hide();
    }

    crossBtn.click(function(){
        menuClose();
    });
```

This is code I am using for Fade in Fade out. This is working perfectly in HTML template but when I use same in wordpress it create problem.
The problem is when I click on any navigation menu item main content fadeIn just for a sec and hide and same problem with menu.